# How to allow non-user to submit data and save it to new user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

The below pic is from the home page of my website. I'm trying to encourage `nil` user to create a goal right from the start.

[image]

```
<%= simple_form_for(Goal.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Upon clicking submit, the `nil` user should become a `guest` user and the goal should be created:

```
  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    if @goal.conceal == true
      @goal.save
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    elsif @goal.guest == true
      @goal.save
      redirect_to signup_url, notice: 'Sign up to see your goal!'
    elsif
      @goal.save
      track_activity @goal
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Field: "Enter Goal"'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And then the `guest` user should be redirected to the signup page:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Once signed in the data entered as a `guest` user should have been saved and applied to the new account.

The `guest` user should then expire in a week:

**lib/goals/guests.rake**

```
namespace :guests do
  desc "Remove guest accounts more than a week old."
  goal :cleanup => :environment do
    User.where(guest: :true).where("created_at < ?", 1.week.ago).destroy_all
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goals
  has_secure_password

  def self.new_guest
    new { |u| u.guest = true }
  end

  def move_to(user)
    goals.update_all(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

**migration**

```
rails g migration add_guest_to_users guest:boolean
```

**user_controller**

```
def create
  @user = params[:user] ? User.new(params[:user]) : User.new_guest
  if @user.save
    current_user.move_to(@user) if current_user && current_user.guest?
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

So what is my question actually?

1. Is my train of thought correct here or is there another way I should be trying to achieve my aims?
2. How can we make `nil` user a `guest` user upon clicking submit? I got much of my inspiration from this [post](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record), but his aims aren't quite the same as mine. He wants to give the user free access to the web app. I just want the non-user to be able to submit a goal as the first part of the signup process.

Comment: Still you are building your app ? :D

Comment: haha,, I know.......

Comment: StackOverflowDriveDevelopment

Comment: So what is your question actually?

Comment: Looks fine - there does not seem to be any condition specified in second `elsif` though.

Comment: `tasks.update_all(user_id: user.id)` i see you have association of goals , and of what are you referring tasks

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I'm sorry do you mean that `current_user` is `nil`? If you have some auth system behind this then you should create  a guest user and sign_in, automatically. What auth system do you use?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I cannot find current_user on api.rubyonrails.org, so no, I don't think it's built in, seems like it's devise or sorcery. A marker to differ a registered user and auto created user. Yup You'd need to put ifs  in several places... Maybe it's not the best solution

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Oh I'm sorry but I just realized that it IS a bad idea... Why not to save a user's goal in his session? That makes sense. You save it in session then advertise him for sign up. When he is signed up you can save that goal and delete it from the session. The only bad part is that you loose that goal if he didn't sign up and his session was cleared. But in that case you wouldn't be able to identify that that saved goal is his anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the user with out validation

```
def create
  @user = params[:user] ? User.new(params[:user]) : User.new_guest
  if @user.save validate: false
    ....
  end
end
```

This way the user does not return error when you know the data is just not right